# Segmentation fault in a link list in C

Tags: c, list, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to write a program for a class that pulls integers from an input text file, puts them into a linked list in descending order, and prints the number, square root, cube root, and fourth roots to an output text file. I have 3 different files. Two .c files and a .h file to link them. I got it to compile but now I get a segmentation fault. Could anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

```
/*          RootTable.c
Author: Chandler Washburn
Description:    Takes an undefined amount of integers from an input file,
                stores and sorts them into a linked list, and prints a 
                chart containing the original number, square root, third
                root, and fourth root.
Compile Instructions: make
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "myLinkedList.h"

/*
Function title: addtolist
Inputs:     file pointer for the input file
Outputs:    a linked list*

Pseudocode:
Begin
    Declare our pointer to the head and set it equal ot NULL
    Declare a string to use for pulling the lines out of the file
    While line string is not NULL(we haven't reached the end)
        Assign head to the value that the insert function returns
End
    */
struct node * addtolist(FILE *finput)
{
   //Declare our pointer to the head and set it equal ot NULL
   struct node *head = NULL;
   //Declare a string to use for pulling the lines out of the file
   char line[20];
   //While line string is not NULL(we haven't reached the end)
   while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), finput) != NULL)
   {
       //Assign head to the value that the insert function returns
       head = insert(line, head);
   }
   //End
   return head;
}

/*
Function title: calculateandoutput
Inputs: Pointer to the head of linked list and output file pointer
Outputs: none

Pseudocode:
Begin   
    While loop to read linked list until NULL
        Declare square_root to be data to the half power
        Declare cube_root to be data to the one third power
        Declare fourth_root to be date to the one fourth power
        Print each of the doubles
        Set head to the next node pointer
End
*/
//Begin
void calculateandoutput(struct node *head, FILE *foutput)
{
   //While loop to read linked list until NULL
   while(head)
   {
       //Declare square_root to be data to the half power
       double square_root = pow(head->data, 0.500000);
       //Declare cube_root to be data to the one third power
       double cube_root = pow(head->data, 0.333333);
       //Declare fourth_root to be date to the one fourth power
       double fourth_root = pow(head->data, 0.250000);
       //Print each of the doubles
       fprintf(foutput, "%d\t%.3lf\t%.3lf\t%.3lf\n", head -> data,
            square_root, cube_root, fourth_root);
       //Set head to the next node pointer
       head = head -> next;
   }
}

/*
Function title: main
Inputs: argc(used for checking errors) and argv(input of filename)
Outputs: none

Pseudocode:
Begin   
    Check for proper amount of inputs
    Assign file pointer for input
    Open input file for reading
    Open input file for reading
    Assign file pointer for output
    Open output file for writing
    Call addtolist function
    Call calculateandoutput function
    Declare node as our current node pointer
    Free each node
End
*/
//Begin
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    //Check for proper amount of inputs
   if(argc!=3)
   {
       printf("Invalid inputs\n");
       return 0;
   }
   //Assign file pointer for input
   FILE* finput = NULL;
   if (finput = fopen(argv[1], "r") == NULL)
    {
       printf("File not found\n");
       return 0;
    }
   // Open input file for reading
   //fopen(finput,"r");
   // Open input file for reading
   //if(finput == NULL)
   
   //Assign file pointer for output
   FILE* foutput = NULL;
   if (foutput = fopen(argv[2], "w") == NULL)
    {
       printf("File not found\n");
       return 0;
    }
   //Open output file for writing
   //fopen(foutput,"w");
   //Call addtolist function
   struct node *head = addtolist(finput);
   //Call calculateandoutput function
   calculateandoutput(head,foutput);
   //Declare node as our current pointer
   struct node *node;
   //Free each node
   for (node = head; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
        free(node);
    }
    //End
   return 0;
}
```

//Here is the myLinkedList.c file

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "myLinkedList.h"



/*
Function title: insert
Inputs: line(string containing our integer), head(the pointer to first node)
Outputs: a struct node

Pseudocode:
Begin   
    Convert the string with our integer into an int
    Create a pointer to a node and set it to the head
    While loop to search for duplicates
    If not found, adds the node to the list
        Create a previous pointer and set equal to NULL(no previous node yet)
        Create a new pointer and malloc enough space for a new node
        Set new nodes data equal to our integer
        Reassign the current pointer to the head
        While loop to check if the current node is < prev
        If there is no previous(smallest value), node is made to be the head
        Else the node is inserted, the previous nodes pointer now points to
            the new node, the current nodes pointer points to the next node
End
*/
//Begin
struct node *insert(char number[], struct node *head)           
{
   //Convert the string with our integer into an int
   int num = atoi(number);
   //Create a pointer to a node and set it to the head
   struct node *node = head;
   //While loop to search for duplicates
   while(node && node -> data != num)                          
       node = node -> next;
   //If not found, adds the node to the list
   if(!node)                                               
   {
       //Create a previous pointer and set equal to NULL(no previous node yet)
       struct node *prev = NULL;
       //Create a new pointer and malloc enough space for a new node
       struct node *new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       //Set new nodes data equal to our integer
       new -> data = num;
       //Reassign the current pointer to the head
       node = head;
       //While loop to check if the current node is < prev
       while(node && node -> data < num)
       {
           printf("%d%", node -> data);
           prev = node;
           node = node -> next;
       }
       //If there is no previous(smallest value), node is made to be the head
       if(!prev)
       {
           new -> next = head;
           head = new;
       }
       //Else the node is inserted, the previous nodes pointer now points to
       //the new node, the current nodes pointer points to the next node
       else
       {
           new -> next = prev -> next;
           prev -> next = new;
       }
   }
   //End
   return head;
}
```

//Here is the myLinkedList.h file

```
#ifndef MYLINKEDLIST_H
#define MYLINKEDLIST_H

/*
Prototype of node
    An int called data that contains our integer
    A pointer to a struct node for the next node
*/
struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *next;  
};

struct node *insert(char number[], struct node *head);

#endif
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this with your debugger? You don't know what a debugger is or how to use it? Well then this is a perfect opportunity to learn it.

Comment: The segmentation fault occurs when (or after) you destroy the list. You basiclly do this: `free(node); node = node->next;`, that is you access memory that you have just freed. Use a temporary variable: `struct node *next = node->next; free(node); node = next;`